# C# detect the type of given URL

Tags: c#, html, sitemap

I'm getting from user a URL to webpage OR sitemap.

What is simplest way to check the type (Sitemap or Webpage) of the given URL?

Thank you!

Comment: Well most (or all?) sitemaps are based on XML, so I would check whether the site  only contains XML or not.

Comment: What do you expect sitemaps, as opposed to a webpage URL to look like? What have you tried so far? Have you considered that you'll have to examine the contents? Are there defined standards for sitemap files? Have you considered how you'd parse those?

Comment: @Daniel "most" doesn't seem a very reliable way of determining a type.

Comment: @DavidArno I only know XML-Sitemaps, but I am not sure if there are other types of them. It was just an idea which could lead the way.

Comment: Definition for sitemap you can see [here](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html). It's xml based textual file.

Comment: @No1Lives4Ever, then you have answered your own question: fetch the contents from the specified URL and check it conforms to that standard. I've described the steps you'll need to research and implement in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having sought clarification of the question, here is what you'll need to do:

1. Check the URL is valid and fetch the contents.
2. Validate the contents against the XML-based sitemap spec at http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html. This can best be done by defining classes that map to urlset and url and by de-serializing the XML to those types.
3. If it's valid XML, then treat it as a sitemap.
4. If it's invalid XML, you may wish to warn the user, or just treat it as a webpage.
5. If not XML, you may treat it as a webpage.